# Looking up whole time-series for specific point from 45 GB file

Tags: python, xarray, code-review, grib

I want to look-up 8760 times for a single lat/lon combo in **less than a second** from 43.82 GB file of wind data containing:

- 8760 times (every hour in a year)
- 721 latitudes (every 0.25° from -90.0° to 90.0°)
- 1440 longitude (every 0.25° from -180.0° to 179.75°)

[image]

The best time we achieved for a single-year look-up was 16 seconds for both u100 and v100 wind speed at 100m vectors. We want to have a **sub-second look-up** for the whole year as such file read will need to happen on **every user request** in our API.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()

    ds = xr.open_dataset("2021.zarr", engine="zarr", chunks={"time": 50})

    print(f"Took {round((time.time() - start_time) * 1000, 2)}ms")

    location = ds.sel(indexers={"latitude": 53.494, "longitude": 9.979}, method='nearest')

    wind_speed = (location.u100.values ** 2 + location.v100.values ** 2) ** 0.5

    print(f"Wind Speed: {wind_speed} m/s")
    print(f"Took {round((time.time() - start_time) * 1000, 2)}ms")
```

Output:

```
Took 94.28ms
Wind Speed: [5.8021994 5.504477  5.4270387 ... 9.563195  8.701231  9.133655 ] m/s
Took 16299.59ms
```

Comment: Round your locations to values that exist in your lat and long dimensions and index on those, rather than asking xr to find the nearest.

Comment: This would be easier if you had 64+GiB of RAM, since even an SSD is going to have difficulty processing 44GiB of data as a file access. If your data is band sequential (BSQ), I strongly urge you to use band interleaved by pixel (BIP) or  even band interleaved by line (BIL) so that the pixels are defragmented.

Comment: @bugmenot123 Hey! Thanks, there is a reason to do the nearest look-up since we would allow users to click anywhere on a map. And in case I do an exact look-up the speed is not that much better. It seems that I am missing a joint index or something major to decrease the speed 20-fold.

Comment: @Vince We have to access many years of wind data, 45 GB is only for the year 2021 of wind temporal data. There's no ability to store all of the data for our use case in RAM.

Comment: I've had a very similar problem recently, but using netCDF instead of zarr. Correctly setting the chunksizes inside the netcdf file greatly improved performance, see this answer for some more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42897111/4288201 (i.e. so this is different than the dask chunks)

Comment: If you need subsecond access to interpolations of a terabyte of fragmented data without a significant RAM investment, somthing in your requirement set is going to have to give. Good, cheap, fast; pick any two.

Comment: @Vince The data is grouped by year, so at most the file size is 33 GB for GRIB, 45 GB for Zarr. Could it be so that the data is indexed by time and then by lat, lon which reduces the speed? Perhaps a grouped index (lat, lon) would solve the issue? I am a software engineer diving into data science so excuse my knowledge... I am trying to understand whether it's possible to achieve such speed with a prebuilt xarray solution.

Comment: @BertCoerver Thanks! Looking into this. What was the performance increase on your end?

Comment: similar order of magnitude as you, from something like 10-15sec to <1sec.